# How to select from outside of a table's columns with a join in Activerecord?

Tags: activerecord

I have the following two tables: user, project

1. User has many projects
2. Project belongs to a user

When I run the following

```
Project.find_by_sql("SELECT projects.*, users.is_admin 
                     FROM projects 
                     JOIN users ON users.id = projects.user_id 
                     WHERE projects.id = 1")
```

The resulting object only includes fields from the `projects` table and `users.is_admin` is not included.

Note: I am aware of `includes`, I don't want to use `includes` because it is 2 queries instead of 1; In this particular case, it is very performance sensitive.

Note 2: I am aware of backing a model with a database view, I only want to do that as a last resort because it is another migration

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!

Turns out it was not a problem!

It was not displayed but if you do `project.is_admin` the field is there.

For future references, you can do:

`project.attributes` to see!